# problem attaching text files to email Intent object

Tags: android

I have a requirement that I need to attach text files generated by my app to the email composer.

I have created my files at my applications private area (getFilesDirectory()).

I am attaching URI of that file path to the email Intent object. I am able to see the attachments in email composer but I am unable to receive the attachments.

I am using this statement attach the files to the intent object

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(context.getFilesDirectory()+"abc.txt"));
```

after doing some search in google I got to know "getFilesDirectory()" is only private to my application and other app's can't access my files (my case its E-mail).

As many of devices may not have SD-card ,I can't kept my files in SD-Card.

Please let me know where I can store my files so that I can attach my files to the email application.
 thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to attach a file from the application area, you need to copy first into the SDCard (temporary or not). If there is no SDCard in the system, you should notify the user. I have been dealing recently with this, and I didn't find any alternative solution.

You can copy the file to the SDCard using the following code:

```
File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
if (sd.canWrite()) {
    String currentDBPath = "\\data\\application.package\\databases\\name";
    String backupDBPath = "name";
    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
    if (currentDB.exists()) {
        FileChannel src;
        try {
            src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            try {
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {                                                    
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Remember to add the following permission: android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: Hi kikoso, thanks for your reply. but I don't want to store my files in SD card. I think we can do it using contentprovider mechanism, but I don't know how to do it exactly. pl. let me know if you have any idea on this.